# Will Silverlight 5 still support OSX

Tags: silverlight, macos

Will Silverlight 5 still support OSX?

Comment: Keep an eye on this thread as well, same question asked here http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Does-Silverlight-5-still-run-on-OS-X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed they have a [Silverlight 5 beta developer runtime for Mac](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-5-beta/) listed on the Silverlight download page, so I would say, yes its still supported.

Comment: I believe Mono supports Silverlight ... called Moonlight.  http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page